# ImportXML in Google Sheets, how to get text attributes

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm a little out of my depth.  I have been able to scrape the text/numbers for the XML path I need. However, the text's color is important and has extra meaning. In html, it's listed like this:

```
<td class="green" title="Charge">10</td>
```

I can get the 10 with the following XML:

```
//*@id="dialdiv"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td
```

How can I capture either the "green" or the "Charge" in addition to the 10?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the attribute, add

```
/@class
```

assuming your xpath is correct, try

```
//*@id="dialdiv"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/@class
```

and to get both at the same time

```
//*@id="dialdiv"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td|//*@id="dialdiv"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/@class
```